# Samba share of disk for network access not working

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have tried to set up a disk for network access with samba, but without success. I suspected the problem might be ownership of the disk, but am unable to change ownership by methods recommended in threads on this site. Output of testparm given below. I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you.

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[Disk]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
```

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    map to guest = Bad User
    security = USER
    server string = Multimedia
    workgroup = COLLAB
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    include = /etc/samba/smbshared.conf


[Disk]
    force user = angelo
    path = /media/angelo/Disk
    read only = No
```

Comment: What problems do you encounter? "Without success" is not specific enough.

Comment: If "angelo" can access the /media/angelo/Disk folder locally on that machine I doubt it's a permissions problem. But your share requires the remote user to pass a username and password to gain access. Did you create a local user in Ubuntu and add him to the samba password database? For example: In order for user:angelo to gain access to the share you need to add him to samba with this command - without quotes: "sudo smbpasswd -a angelo"

Comment: I was able to mount one drive from the network but not another drive using the conf files above, and thought the issue might have to do with different ownership, but in fact the ownership was the same. I went to Nautilus and switched on sharing for both drives, and now they are accessible from the network. I had in fact added angelo as a samba user previously, so the problem seems not to have had to do with that. I just did not realize that I would have to manually turn on sharing in Nautilus. I will test further tomorrow.

Comment: Just for the record, can anyone suggest a good straightforward guide to file sharing in samba/Ubuntu? None of the resources I find seem to agree on a single method, and this becomes very confusing. Thanks for your help.